# Tcp Socket starts dropping connection after a time period in java

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a java server which listens for client requests.
It is a multi threading environment. After a time period server starts rejecting the new connections and also drops already created established connections.
Java Server is running on linux machine.

Can Anyone help whether it is machine issue or code issue.
linux have 1677216 tcp_wmem and tcp_rmem.

Comment: You really should post your source code to get help from other people IMO.

Comment: Clearly your Java server has a resource leak, probably a socket leak, somewhere.

Comment: Actually when there were only 600 concurrent tcp connections then it was working fine. but when i increase the load upto 1000 connections. the after 3 days it starts degrading the number of connections.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give an exact answer to your question without seeing your code, but some suggestions you may want to try are, limiting your thread count to a smaller number and checking whether you are closing sockets correctly or not.

Comment: Yes thread count is normal actualy i am using a thread pool and once i close a connection the thread still remains in the thread pool. Then if any new request arrives i use old thread from the pool to start communication.